# Rewriting Wordpress Dynamic URLS. Through .Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have url pattern like this.

site.com/page-name?variable-name=variable value

I want this to be  site.com/variable - value

I' am not good in rewrite api. Please guide me through .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1-%2? [R,L]
```